# coverting arraylist to array in less than O(n)

Tags: algorithm, arraylist, data-structures

I am currently working on program and want to convert ArrayList to an array but in less than O(n) time.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {




    if (list.get(i) != null) {
                                 arr[i] = list.get(i);
                             }
                     }
```

Comment: _"convert ArrayList to an array but in less than O(n) time"_ -- and what makes you think that's even possible? It is not clear what you are really asking. You should at least add a language tag ([tag:java]?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If n is the length of the list then O(n) means in this case that you look at each element in the list and copy it.
Now you say you want to convert it in less than O(n). This means you have to ignore some elements in the list. if not it would be O(n) again. But which do you ignore? Remember you are not allowed to look at all elements else it would be in O(n) again.
Let's say you know that the list contains booleans where n/2 are true and the others are false. In the best-case scenario all true values would be in the first half of the list.
Now you can stop iterating at n/2 of the list but you need to add the false values again to your Array. Now you are in O(n) again.
Let's make another assumption. You can always ignore the last value of the list. This means that you only iterate n-1 times that then is O(n-1) but in big O notation, you ignore constants so it gets O(n) again.

It is not possible to copy all n elements of a list to an Array in lower than O(n).